# How to check installed DB drivers (OLEDB, ODBC) in runtime

Tags: .net, c#-3.0

I have a program written on c# that works with MS Access database. Everything went fine, but SUDDENLY I've encountered a problem. When there is no MS Office installed on a computer, there is no OLEDB provider too.

So. Is that true, Open Office uses ODBC connection to access MS Access database? And how can I check in my code which one provider is installed? Should I check Windows Registry?

Comment: Your application should install what it requires to run. (I.E. search for AccessDatabaseEngine)

Comment: Is that wrong to add Load and Store methods identical to existing with only one difference - usage of odbc connection, adapter and command instead of oledb versions? Why should I force user to install AccessDatabaseEngine?

Comment: It's your call. Change your program to use Odbc or stay with OleDb and install the database engine. I prefer to use OleDb but without context it is just an opinion. (And also, using Odbc don't avoid the install of some drivers if they are missing)